# Avoiding unchecked warnings when using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, unchecked

I'd like to mock a call on `ScheduledExecutorService` to return mock of `ScheduledFuture` class when method `schedule` is invoked. The following code compiles and works correctly:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Mockito.mock(ScheduledExecutorService.class);
    ScheduledFuture future = Mockito.mock(ScheduledFuture.class);
    Mockito.when(executor.schedule(
        Mockito.any(Runnable.class),
        Mockito.anyLong(),
        Mockito.any(TimeUnit.class))
    ).thenReturn(future); // <-- warning here
```

except that I'm getting unchecked warning in the last line:

```
found raw type: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture
  missing type arguments for generic class java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<V>

 unchecked method invocation: method thenReturn in interface org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing is applied to given types
  required: T
  found: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture

unchecked conversion
  required: T
  found:    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture
```

Is it possible to somehow avoid these warnings?

Code like `ScheduledFuture<?> future = Mockito.mock(ScheduledFuture.class);` doesn't compile.

Comment: What type is your `ScheduledFuture` intended to be bound to in your actual code?

Comment: It is `ScheduledFuture<?>`, as I'm submitting just `Runnable`.

Comment: If this particular test functions fine then, I wouldn't worry about it too much.  There may be a way to remove the warning if it's type-bound to `Object`, but I doubt that this would be worth changing.  Could you paste the specific test and the test code so that we could replicate it in our own environments?  Just enough to replicate the warning will do.

Comment: @Makoto I've updated test with mock declaration, I think it should be enough to replicate. I cannot have warning here, as I'm compiling project in environment where all compiler warnings are prohibited.

Comment: Well...that's unfortunate.  Okay then, I see the plight.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All warnings go away when alternative way of mock specification is used:

```
    ScheduledFuture<?> future = Mockito.mock(ScheduledFuture.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(future).when(executor).schedule(
        Mockito.any(Runnable.class),
        Mockito.anyLong(),
        Mockito.any(TimeUnit.class)
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the annotation on method level.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```